# pyInstaller changing dll and pyd output location

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use pyInstaller to package a wxpython application. I looking for a variation of the "one-folder" mode whereby the dlls and pyds are not stored in the top-level directory but in a subdirectory instead (like "dlls" or "libs").

This is the spec file currently:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import os

a = Analysis\
(
    ["..\\job_scraper\\load_gui.py"],
    pathex        = ["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Projects\\python\\PyInstaller\\load_gui"],
    hiddenimports = [],
    hookspath     = None,
    runtime_hooks = None
)

a_binaries = []
for (name, path, data_type) in a.binaries:
    (non_ext, ext) = os.path.splitext(name)
    if(ext in [".pyd", ".dll"]):
        a_binaries.append((os.path.join("libs", name), path, data_type))
    else:
        a_binaries.append((name, path, data_type))

a.binaries = TOC(a_binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE\
(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    exclude_binaries = True,
    name             = "load_gui.exe",
    debug            = False,
    strip            = None,
    upx              = True,
    console          = False
)

coll = COLLECT\
(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [("control.csv", "..\\job_scraper\\control.csv", "DATA")],
    strip = None,
    upx   = True,
    name  = "load_gui"
)
```

This does to put the dlls (not the pyds) into a lib folder, however it seems to do this after linking and so the program fails to launch because it can't find the expected dlls.

Comment: I am facing the same Problem. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: I've looked into it. It requires modification of the bootloader source code. There is a section in the code that defines where it looks for .pyd, .dll, etc. I haven't made any progress beyond that, as I haven't been able to get MingW to build the bootloader.

Comment: Too bad, this would be a nice option to have in pyinstaller.  I'll see if I can work on that at some point.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `sys.path` doesn't include your subdirectories. So when the program runs, it doesn't know where to look for your .dll or .pyd files.

Of course putting the code `sys.path.append("relative/path/to/your/subdirectories")` on top of your main script would come to mind. But one again, this code is only executed after everything is loaded and in place.

According to this [blog](http://unafaltadecomprension.blogspot.jp/2014/07/pyinstaller-separating-executable-from.html), the solution is using the runtime hook of pyinstaller. 
Runtime hook tells the bootstrapping code to run any of your arbitrary code before your main script runs - before importing any stuff.

## 1. Preparation

Create a `hooker.py` which will add all your custom paths to `sys.path`. Put it somewhere and do it 1 time only.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "lib"))    # for pyd
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "windll")) # for dll
```

## 2. Tell pyinstaller to include the hooker.py

with spec file:

```
a = Analysis\
(
    ["..\\job_scraper\\load_gui.py"],
    pathex        = ["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Projects\\python\\PyInstaller\\load_gui"],
    hiddenimports = [],
    hookspath     = None,
    runtime_hooks = "absolute/path/to/hooker.py"  # <----- add it here
)
```

or with commandline:

`pyinstaller --runtime-hook="absolute/path/to/hooker.py" the_rest_parameters`

## 3. Run pyinstaller

As usually, it will create `dist/your_main_script_name` folder which contains the `exe` file, manifest, library.zip, and a bunch of `.dll` and `.pyd`

## 4. Create custom folders

Now you can create a `windll` folder and `lib` or anything that you add to `sys.path` at step 1. Then move all `.pyd` files to `lib` and all `.dll` files to `windll`.

Run your `exe` and it will crash! So move back these below files to parent folder.

- pythonXX.dll  ,   where XX is your python version
- VCRUNTIME140.dll
- pywintypesXX.dll,  where XX is your python version and if it is included

These files are needed for the bootstrap so we cannot move them without modifying the bootstrap code.

Run the `exe` again and it should work normally.

---

Soon you will get bored of repeating all of the above over and over again.
So here is what I have been doing.

Create `compiler.bat` with the content similar to:

```
pyinstaller --runtime-hook="absolute/path/to/hooker.py" --onedir --icon path/to/icon ^
--exclude-module=UnNeeded_module_A ^
--exclude-module=UnNeeded_module_B ^
%1

@echo off
for %%F in (%1) do set pyi_output=%%~nxF
set pyi_output=%pyi_output:~0,-3%

mkdir dist\%pyi_output%\windll
mkdir dist\%pyi_output%\lib

move dist\%pyi_output%\*.dll dist\%pyi_output%\windll
move dist\%pyi_output%\*.pyd dist\%pyi_output%\lib

move dist\%pyi_output%\windll\python36.dll dist\%pyi_output%
move dist\%pyi_output%\windll\VCRUNTIME140.dll dist\%pyi_output%
if exist dist\%pyi_output%\windll\pywintypes36.dll (
    move dist\%pyi_output%\windll\pywintypes36.dll dist\%pyi_output%
)

pause
```

To not mess up your project, create a copy of your code folder and place this `compile.bat` inside. Then, just drag and drop your `main_script.py` to `compile.bat`.

The `pause` command keeps the console windows open so that you know if the compilation is successful or not.

Comment: I followed this answer but the app fails to launch after I moved some modules into the specified folder. I added a print in `hooker.py` and noticed the `sys.path` already included the desired paths, meaning the rt-hooker is working as expected but the app wouldn't find modules in those paths, any advice?

Comment: Continuing... I'm using pyinstaller 4.2 + python 3.9, here is the output in consoles which you can see the paths were added into `sys.path` already. `['C:\\Users\\nochenon\\dist\\XXX\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\nochenon\\dist\\XXX', 'C:\\Users\\nochenon\\dist\\XXX\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\nochenon\\dist\\XXX\\dll', 'C:\\Users\\nochenon\\dist\\XXX\\deps']`

Comment: @nochenon You have to do a binary search to find which `dll` or `pyd` files must not be moved. Keep your current compiling setting. Move all `dll` file out to see if the app launches as it should. Then move half of the `dll` file back in `windll` to see if the app crashes. If it is, move half of them out and in again until you find a suspected file that should be outside.

Comment: @nochenon If you have other app running well with this compiling setting, you could also whitelist the same files that are in `windll` and `lib` folder of this app too. This will speed up your process.

Comment: I end up modifying the "pyimod03_importers.py" inside the pyinstaller module to get it working: `sys._MEIPASS = pyi_os_path.os_path_join(sys._MEIPASS, "deps")`, I can move everything except python39.dll & base_library.zip into `deps` folder. I know this is not a recommanded way, but the result seems prettry well.
Note: if `mulitprocessing` is used, `pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py` should be modified as well.

Answer (score -4):

another way, new loadmyapp.c:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    execv("yourapp/app.exe", argv);
}
```

gcc -o loadmyapp loadmyapp.c

./loadmyapp